# Array Out Of Bounds

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexing

The purpose of this program is to find the kth smallest element in an array without sorting the array using a recursive and nonrecursive decrease and conquer type method.

I was hoping someone could look over my code and try to help me with my array out of bounds error(s).

The method that is throwing these errors is the recursive selection the non recursive selection works fine.

My driver is also attached and everything should compile if you want to test my code.

```
public class KthSmallest
{
private int counter;
private int term;
private int[] A;

int SelectionNonRecursive(int A[], int kthSmallest, int sizeOfA)
{   
    this.A = A;
    if(kthSmallest == 1 || kthSmallest == sizeOfA)
    {
        return (LinearSearch(kthSmallest, sizeOfA));
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeOfA; i++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j<sizeOfA; j++)
            {
                if(A[i] < A[j])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if((sizeOfA - counter) == kthSmallest)
            {
                return A[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int SelectionRecursive(int A[], int kthSmallest, int sizeOfA)
{
    this.A = A;
    return Selection_R(0, sizeOfA - 1, kthSmallest);
}

int Selection_R(int l, int r, int kthSmallest)
{
    if(l<r)
    {
    if(kthSmallest == 1 || kthSmallest == A.length)
    {
        return (LinearSearch(kthSmallest, A.length));
    }
    else
    {
        int s = LomutoPartition(l, r);
        if(s == kthSmallest - 1)
        {
            return A[s];
        }
        else if(s > (A[0] + kthSmallest - 1))
        {
            Selection_R(l, s-1, kthSmallest);
        }
        else
        {
            Selection_R(s+1, r, kthSmallest); 
        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}

int LomutoPartition(int l, int r)
{
    int pivot = A[l];
    int s = l;
    for(int i = l+1; i<r; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] < pivot)
        {
            s += 1;
            swap(A[s], A[i]);
        }
    }
    swap(A[l], A[s]);
    return s;
}

public void swap(int i, int j)
{
    int holder = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = holder;
}

int LinearSearch(int kthSmallest, int sizeOfA)
{
    term = A[0];
    for(int i=1; i<sizeOfA; i++)
    {
        if(kthSmallest == 1)
        {
            if(term > A[i])
            {
                term = A[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(term < A[i])
            {
                term = A[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return term;
}
}

public class KthDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    KthSmallest k1 = new KthSmallest();
    int[] array = {7,1,5,9,3};
    System.out.print(k1.SelectionRecursive(array, 3, array.length));


}
}
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace.

Comment: Where exactly is the exception showing? Can you post the Stack Trace?

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem? On what lines are you getting these errors? What did your debugger tell you?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: PLEEEASE! Show us WHERE it happens. (There really should be a function in SO that you can't post w/o a stacktrace if the question contains the word "Exception" :D ) (sorry, user, it really happens that often)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `LomutoPartition` method, you are passing the array elements in your `swap` method: -

```
swap(A[s], A[i]);  // Inside for loop
```

and

```
swap(A[l], A[s]);  // Outside for loop
```

And your swap method considers them as `indices`: -

```
public void swap(int i, int j)  <-- // `i` and `j` are elements A[s] and A[i]
{
    int holder = A[i];  <-- // You are accessing them as indices(A[i] -> A[A[s]])
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = holder;
}
```

That is why you are getting that exception. Because, if any element in array is greater than size, it will blast out.

You should *change your invocation* to: -

```
swap(s, i);   // Inside for loop
```

and

```
swap(l, s);   // Outside for loop
```

respectively. And leave your method as it is.

Note that, you should pass array indices, and not array elements. If you pass array elements, then the swapping in the method will not be reflected in your array. Because, your method will have its own copy of your elements.

Comment: You're welcome. And next time when you post your question, please post the full stack trace. It will be easier to trace the exceptions